# PHP Session 5.4 to 5.6

Tags: php, session

I have created a website lately with a group of students, but were having some troubles.
We created the website in php 5.4 on a localhost and it worked perfectly.
But now we wanted to get the site online and the webhosting is using a different version of php(5.6). 
So now the session does not start.
It redirects us to the homepage, but we are not logged in.
We were thinking that it was because of the version of php, since it did work at first.

```
<?php
include_once 'connect.php';
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['gebruiker'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql="select email_adres from gebruiker where email_adres='".$user_check".'";
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['username'];
if(!isset($login_session)){
    header('Location: login.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
else{
    header('Location: acountgegevens.php');
}
?>
```

```
<?php
include_once 'connect.php';
function logincheck(){
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $error = 0;
        // declare variables
        $email = null;
        $password = null;

        // check if email address has been set
        if (isset($_POST['email_adres']) && 
           !empty($_POST['email_adres'])) {
            $email = addslashes($_POST['email_adres']);
        }

        // check if password has been set
        if (isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
            $password = md5($_POST['password']);
        }
        if ($email == null || $password == null) {
            $error = 1;
        }

        // query database for user credentials
        $db = new PDO('**');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * 
                                   FROM gebruiker 
                                   WHERE email_adres = :email 
                                     AND wachtwoord = :password 
                                   LIMIT 1");
        $statement->execute(array(':email' => $email, ':password' => $password));

        $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        if (!$result) {
            $error = 1;
        } else {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['gebruiker'] = $email;

            var_dump($_SESSION);

?>
<script>location.href='index.php'</script>
<?php

        }
        return $error;
    }
}
?>
```

These two files are included, but we cant figure it out.

Could someone help?

Comment: `session_start();` should on the first line.

Comment: Yeah, `session_start()` must be the first thing if the included *connect.php* uses session variables.

Comment: You can't mix and match different database connection API's, either use `PDO` or use `MySQLi`.

Comment: You should use prepared statements everywhere. Any particular reason you are using `PDO` and `mysqli`? You also should look at the PHP password hashing/verifying functions. `$ses_sql` is never executed so you can't fetch it.

Answer (score 0):

I would hazzard a guess that your `connect.php` has not been changed to match the hosting companies `host/user/password` and therefore is outputting an error message.

This of course means that `session_start()` , which was placed after the `connect.php` and therefore after your script has attempted to send something to the browser, will not work.

You are only seeing the result of the failed `session_start()` but I would check the `connect.php` is configured correctly for its new hosting location